# How do I define multiple routes for one request in Silex?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

Is there a way in Silex to define multiple routes for one request. I need to be able to define two routes for one page (both routes takes to the same page). Here's my current controller:

```
$app->get('/digital-agency', function() use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('digital_agency.html', $data);
});
```

It works when I duplicate the function like this:

```
$app->get('/digital-agency', function() use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('digital_agency.html', $data);
});

$app->get('/agencia-digital', function() use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('digital_agency.html', $data);
});
```

So, any idea of a more clean way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can save the closure to a variable and pass that to both routes:

```
$digital_agency = function() use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('digital_agency.html', $data);
};

$app->get('/digital-agency', $digital_agency);
$app->get('/agencia-digital', $digital_agency);
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the [assert](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/api/Silex/Route.html#method_assert) method to match certain expressions.

```
$app->get('/{section}', function() use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('digital_agency.html', $data);
})
->assert('section', 'digital-agency|agencia-digital');
```